# Internal Storage - open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estou com um problema que já faz alguns dias que não consigo resolver. Eu tenho uma lista de arquivos que estão salvos no Internal Storage e o que é preciso fazer é zipar esses arquivos quando o usuários deixar a atividade. O problema é que quando finalmente eu chamo o método para fazer tal coisa ele simplesmente não consegue encontrar os arquivos, mesmo com o caminho correto! Resumidamente a forma que utilizo para criar e recuperar esses arquivos é criar um `openFileOutput()` e depois obter a referência com `new File(getFileDir(), "nome do arquivo")`.

**Métodos**

```
private void zip(List<File> files, File zipFile) {
        try {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
            ZipOutputStream zos  = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

            for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
                File f = files.get(i);

                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(f.getName()));

                int len;
                while ((len = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }

                zos.closeEntry();
                fis.close();
            }
            fos.close();
            zos.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public boolean build(List<File> files, File zipFile) {      
        zip(files, zipFile);
        /* Eu sei que esse retorno não faz tanto sentido */
        return true;
    }
```

**Activity**

```
public class BotActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

   /* ... */

   @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        startJob();
    }

   /* Aqui é onde eu obtenho o arquivo e salvo na lista
     onde posteriormente será zipada */
   private void talk(String text) {
        request = new SynthesizeSpeechPresignRequest();
        request.withVoiceId(VoiceId.Vitoria);
        request.withOutputFormat(OutputFormat.Ogg_vorbis);
        request.withText(text);

        Needle.onBackgroundThread().execute(() -> {
            URL pssu = client.getPresignedSynthesizeSpeechUrl(request);

            try {
                byte[] data = new byte[1024];

                ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                InputStream stream = pssu.openStream();

                int len;
                while ((len = stream.read(data)) != -1) {
                    byteBuffer.write(len);
                }

                String fileName = text.concat(".ogg");

              FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                               fos.write(byteBuffer.toByteArray());
                               fos.close();

                audios.add(new File(getFilesDir(), fileName));

                byteBuffer.close();
                stream.close();


                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(pssu.toString());
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    private void startJob() {
        File zipFile = new File(getFilesDir(), SPFFile.SPF_FILE_NAME);
        if (spfFile.build(audios, zipFile)) {

            GooglePlayDriver googlePlayDriver = new GooglePlayDriver(this);
            FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher  = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(googlePlayDriver);

            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                   extras.putString(Constant.INTENT_JOB_KEY,  data.getKey());

            Job uploadJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                    .setService(UploadJob.class)
                    .setExtras(extras)
                    .setTag("UploadJob")
                    .setRecurring(false)
                    .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(0, 0))
                    .setReplaceCurrent(true)
                    .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
                    .setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK)
                    .build();

            dispatcher.mustSchedule(uploadJob);
        }
    }
}
```

**StackTrace**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Me desculpem pelas censuras, mas é porque o código é de um produto não lançado. Mas garanto que elas não atrapalham no entendimento da situação.

PS: Rodei o mesmo código com a IntelliJ IDEA para observar como o código funcionava no desktop e tudo correu como esperado.

Comment: Pelo que dá para ver na imagem, na parte do erro, parece que o nome do arquivo tem um espaço entre o 1 e o ponto: "file 1 .ogg". Penso que esse espaço está a mais.

Comment: Olá @ramaral, na imagem há sim um espaço, porém foi culpada da censura que eu fiz. No texto original não existe esse espaço entre o nome do arquivo e a extensão. Mas no nome em si existe sim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Android usa o kernel do linux. Quando você tentar ler um arquivo no sistema linux, é necessário escapar os espaços para que seja entendido corretamente.

```
    String str = "diretorio/do/arquivo/arquivo a.txt";
    str = str.replaceAll("\\s", "\\\\ ");

    // SAIDA : diretorio/do/arquivo/arquivo\ a.txt
```

Comment: Acertou na mosca! Eu já tinha voltado aqui para responder. Percebi que sistema de arquivo do armazenamento interno é case sensitive. Havia arquivos com maiúsculas no nome em alguns lugares e em outros não, então normalizei todos.

Comment: @IvanSilva você disse que rodou no IntelliJ IDEA ... No windows né?

Comment: Isso mesmo, no Windows. O que mudei foi apenas as chamadas de `openFileOutput()` por `FileOutputStream()` e os arquivos estavam todos com o nome em minúsculo.